# How to organize @RestController @Controller structure url-mapping and internal structure wise?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

In our web-app we have both @Controller classes and @RestController.

How would you suggest to organize them in our internal project structure project (packages/module) and url mapping wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Concerning Package structure you have two options. layer vs
   component packaging.

   **Layer packaging** preserves policy that layer beans are in same packages (e.g. `UserController`, `InvoiceController` are in
   `com.example.application.web` package and `UserService`,
   `InvoiceService` are in `com.example.application.service` package).
   This is most common in the wild.

   **Component packaging** preserves policy package per feature (e.g. `UserController`, `UserService` are in
   `com.example.application.user` and `InvoiceController`,
   `InvoiceService` are in `com.example.application.invoice`).

   I had experience only with Layer packaging so far and gained opinion
   that Component packaging would solve a lot of problems (especially
   coupling problems as you can often use package private beans instead
   of public). So if it would be up to me, I would go with latter
   approach.

   But your team has to decide which structure to use and stick with
   it.

   You can read more about pros and cons in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260302/program-design-package-by-feature-vs-layer-or-both)
2. Concerning controller naming, it depends if you are doing
   REST or VIEW templating. Rest APIs would be good to reflect URL
   resource in Controller name. If you are handling VIEW templating
   with Spring MVC, it would be good to reflect view names in
   controller. This naturally creates policy one view/REST resource per
   controller, which I would follow for sure.
3. URL structure depends on your domain. If you have a lot of
   resources, views you want to group them into categories and reflect
   these categories in URL ("/shopping/invoice", "/profile/user"). I
   don't know your architecture (SOA vs Monolith), but in SOA
   architecture may use root level URLs for routing to particular
   services. So your service may naturally handle some separate domain
   concerns.