# Fetch many to one hibernate in JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

How can I fetch a many to one relationship in a JSP page? I tried

`<s:property value="group.division.name" />`

but no data appeared on the JSP.

The `Group` can belong to one `Division`.

```
public class Group implements java.io.Serializable {
    ..
    private Division division;
    ..

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "div_id", nullable = false)
    public Division getDivision() {
            return this.division;
    }

    public void setDivision(Division division) {
            this.division = division;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Division implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    private String name;
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getName() {
            return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "division")
    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
            return this.groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
            this.groups = groups;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, its because of your `FetchType.LAZY`. Remove that part, it'll fetch it eagerly by default, if I'm not mistaken -- didn't touch Hibernate for a long time, since its `@ManyToOne`.

`EAGER` will try to use an outer join to retrieve the associated object, while `LAZY` will only trigger an explicit `SELECT` statement when the associated object is accessed for the first time. Now, here is caveat, the `LAZY` thing will only work, and fire an explicit `SELECT` to load the related entities, within the transaction. In your case, the transaction is already ended, it seems; therefore its not able to retrieve the related entity.

You might like to read [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100115/i-found-jpa-or-alike-dont-encourage-dao-pattern), it discussed this thing briefly, in the question and one of the answer.

Comment: So should it be `FetchType.EAGER`?